# How to avoid padding summand in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have two tensors `A`, with shape `(25, 1010, 7, 512)`, and `B`, with shape `(10, 7`).

I would like to add `B` to the first 10 slices using the second dimension of `A` in a way which could be done in Numpy as:

```
A[:, :10, :, :] += B[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis]
```

(It's not important that the original tensor be updated, I'd be fine with either an in place update or a new tensor being created).

Of course this can't be done directly in tensorflow, and `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` doesn't seem to work for this case because the slices aren't into the final dimension of the tensor to be updated. Is there any way to accomplish this sparsely, or do I need to pad `B` out by a factor of 100?

EDIT: I messed up the numpy example when converting it from an in place update to an addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since OP is trying to do an item assignment [that is not available in TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33131) (but available in PyTorch!!), you could use `tf.concat` to append over axis 1 the remaining tensor after the sum.

Please see my updated code -

```
import tensorflow as tf
#tf.__version__ = '2.3.1'

#numpy arrays with your shapes
a = np.random.random((25, 1010, 7, 512))
b = np.random.random((10, 7))

#convert to tensors
A = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
B = tf.convert_to_tensor(b)

#Broadcasted sum >> concat with remaining array over axis 1
A = tf.concat([A[:,:10,:,:] + B[None, :, :, None], A[:,10:,:,:]], axis=1)
A.shape
```

```
TensorShape([25, 1010, 7, 512])
```

Just to check that you are getting the same answer as you would with item assignment in NumPy, you can do this -

```
#Item assigment sum over numpy arrays
a[:,:10,:,:] += b[None,:,:,None]

#Convert a to tensor and check against A from above.
tf.reduce_all(tf.convert_to_tensor(a) == A)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be suprised if you can literally use `np.newaxis` since AFAIK that is just a pseudonym for `None`. There is also `tf.newaxis` to make it more explicit, although I also prefer `None` simply because it's shorter.

Comment: wasnt aware of the `tf.newaxis`. Thanks for that info!

Comment: Ah I actually botched the numpy example, let me rewrite what I want.

Comment: you want it summed over each of the blocks of 10 from the 1010 elements?

Comment: The key point is that I would like the final output to have shape (25, 1010, 7, 512), with the first 10 slices having been updated.

Comment: so you DONT want it to broadcast sum over axis=1 but want it broadcasted over axis=0 and axis=3?

Comment: item assignment is not allowed in tensorflow sadly (even though its available in pytorch :( check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33131)). I have updated by code with a solution that should be simpler than dealing with `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` though.

Comment: Added a check so that you can be sure that it gives the expected solution. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal That's actually what I ended up implementing in my code so I've accepted it as the answer. I was hoping there was some way to use scatter though.

Comment: Scatter required some complex meshgrids and all, I could help you implement it, but its not worth it, trust me.

Comment: It was a good question however, I haven't come across a similar situation before!